# Double integral with inconsistent results compared to wolfram

Tags: r, vectorization, numerical-integration

After solving many issues with the below integral, I still need some help to get to a proper solution. I tried to reduce the complexity as much as possible, thanks for your help.

Lets take this example:

```
b <- function(t) { # variable upper bound
  if (t<0) t
  else 0
}
```

Doubleintegral:

```
f<-function(g,t){
    exp(75*g)*
    exp(-35*t-((-t + 0.001283464)^2)/0.0001468898)
}

result <- (integrate(Vectorize(function(t) integrate(function(g) f(g,t), -2.5,b(t))$value), -2, 2, stop.on.error=FALSE)$value)
```

This gives me:

```
> (integrate(Vectorize(function(t) integrate(function(g) f(g,t), -2.5,b(t))$value), -2, 2, stop.on.error=FALSE)$value)
[1] 0.0002256195
```

While Wolfram Alpha gives me only 0.00012.. 
[Link to Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integration%20[%2F%2Fmath%3Aexp%2875*x%29*exp%28-35*y-%28%28-y%20%2B%200.001283464%29%5E2%29%2F0.0001468898%29%2F%2F]%20[%2F%2Fmath%3Adx%20dy%2F%2F]%20for%20x%20from%20[%2F%2Fmath%3A-2.5%2F%2F]%20to%20[%2F%2Fmath%3Amin%280%2Cy%29%2F%2F]%20for%20y%20from%20[%2F%2Fmath%3A-2%2F%2F]%20to%20[%2F%2Fmath%3A2%2F%2F])

I checked the function in Wolfram and it is the same as here. Does someone has a solution to solve this problem? thank you very much!

Comment: When I click on your W|A link, I get a message "standard computation time exceeded". That sounds suspicious.

Comment: PS. anonymous downvoter, explain your reasons please.

Comment: The Link works for me. 

copy past this to wolfram: `integration [//math:exp(75*x)*exp(-35*y-((-y + 0.001283464)^2)/0.0001468898)//] [//math:dx dy//] for x from [//math:-2.5//] to [//math:min(0,y)//] for y from [//math:-2//] to [//math:2//]`

Comment: Yes, it gives a numeric result. But did you also see the box underneath with that warning message? It may be that the computation was stopped prematurely.

Comment: omg I did not see that message and I actually have a pro account. If i extend the computation time it gives me the same result. thanks for your hint.

Comment: You might want to put that as an answer, or edit your question to note that you've solved it.

Answer (score 0):

By extending the computation time, the results are consistent. thanks @Hong Ooi